# Default menu.html.twig does not print below first level

Tags: theming, navigation

Using Drupal 8, trying to integrate a custom theme we statically coded in house, and this is our first foray into Drupal 8.

I copied menu.html.twig verbatim from the core directory into my theme's templates, and no matter what I try, I can't get any links beyond the first level to print. When I try to dump item.below, I get an empty array.

```
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.  
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul>
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <li{{ item.attributes }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

To me, this seems like one of the lowest, most basic thing I can do in a Drupal theme, literally print out a menu. What am I missing? What can I check to make sure everything is right? As far as I know, I haven't done anything out of the ordinary.

I checked the block, and it's set to unlimited levels, starting at level 1.

Comment: Are the links set to Show Expanded on the menu link itself?

Comment: @Kevin That did end up being the fix, but for some reason it wasn't working until yesterday. I'm not sure if I had something configured wrong or some wires crossed that were causing errors, but checking that box was the ultimate fix.

Comment: Please don't add answers to the question, there's an answer box below just for that :)